# Need to execute async function for every element of the array but dispatch action with progress only

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming, redux-observable

I am quite new in RxJS, still trying to figure out how to implement different features using it.
I need help regarding the implementation of an observable, tried so many ways but none seems to work.

I have this function:

```
export function automateParameterEdit(tunId) {
  const progress$ = new Subject();

  const process$ = defer(async () => {
    const tun = await updateStatus(tunId, 'autoTun');
    progress$.next({ ...tun , progress: '0' });
    return { rules: tun.rules, tun };
  }).pipe(
    flatMap(({ rules, tun }) =>
      from(Object.values(rules)).pipe(
        concatMap(rule => autoEditParameters(tunId, rule.ruleId, tun.rulesetId)),
        scan((acc, curr) => acc + 1, 0),
        map(progress => {
          progress$.next({ ...tun, progress: progress / Object.values(rules).length * 100 });
        }),
        catchError(e => {
          // whatever
        }),
        finalize(async () => {
          // whatever
        })
      )
    )
  );

  return merge(progress$, process$);
}
```

So, right now, the action is being dispatched twice, once because of the `progress$.next({ ...tun, progress: progress / Object.values(rules).length * 100 });` that emits the new tun progress, and the second time I believe it's because of the execution of: `concatMap(rule => autoEditParameters(tunId, rule.ruleId, tun.rulesetId))`

Let's say there are 4 rules (`Object.values(rules).length === 4`). In the console I see 4 x 2 = 8 actions dispatched, half of them have invalid payload.

What I want to do is execute the `autoEditParameters(tunId, rule.ruleId, tun.rulesetId)` which btw is async, and after each execution I want to emit the progress (`progress$.next({ ...tun, progress: progress / Object.values(rules).length * 100 });`).

How do I stop the invalid actions from being dispatched and only execute the async `autoEditParameters` and dispatch progress?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Subject`!

You only need a subject when you need to "manually" push a value through a stream.  But, in your case, you just want to modify (`map`) emissions into a different shape.

So, you can just get rid of the subject.  There's no need to merge `process$` with `progress$`; you can simply return `progress$`;

```
function automateParameterEdit(tunId) {
  const process$ = defer(async () => {
    const tun = await updateStatus(tunId, 'autoTun');
    return { rules: tun.rules, tun };
  }).pipe(
    flatMap(({ rules, tun }) =>
      from(Object.values(rules)).pipe(
        concatMap(rule => autoEditParameters(tunId, rule.ruleId, tun.rulesetId)),
        scan((acc, curr) => acc + 1, 0),
        map(progress => {
          return { ...tun, progress: progress / Object.values(rules).length * 100 };
        })
      )
    )
  );

  return process$;
}
```

Here are a couple StackBlitz samples:

- [Original](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63132975-original?file=index.ts)
- [Possible Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63132975-solution?file=index.ts)

> and after each execution I want to emit the progress

Not sure if you meant you just wanted emit the numeric percent (not an object), but that could easily be done.  Sometimes breaking it down into smaller functions can make it easier to follow:

```
function automateParameterEdit(tunId): Observable<number> {
  return updateTun(tunId).pipe(
    flatMap(processRules)
  );
}

function updateTun(tunId): Observable<Tun> {
  return defer(async () => updateStatus(tunId, 'autoTun'))
}

function processRules(tun: Tun): Observable<number> {
  return from(tun.rules).pipe(
    concatMap(rule => autoEditParameters(tun.id, rule.ruleId, tun.rulesetId)),
    scan(acc => acc + 1, 0),
    map(doneCount => doneCount / tun.rules.length * 100),
    startWith(0),
  )
}
```

Here, `updateTun()` just wraps the async function and returns an observable, so it will be executed whenever it is subscribed to.

`processRules()` takes a `Tun` and returns an `Observable<number>` that is the progress percent. `startWith` just emits an intial value of `0`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-63132975-solution-2?file=index.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very useful! Can you help me with one more problem I have? I need to call a function at the end, when all the rules have been processed (after every rule has called autoEditParameters). How can I do that?

Comment: You are welcome! You can use the finalize operator to execute a function when an observable completes. So, `flatMap(processRules.pipe(finalize(yourFunction))`